# How to add ActionScript 3.0 code to a brand new .fla Flash project?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am just trying to add a "Hello World" or a program that draw a circle to a brand new project in Flash Professional CS5.

So the project file is has a  .fla extension

And I think the code is supposed to be added to the "action" of frame 1?  But I don't see any place where I can open up a box to type in any code?  How can that be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the actions panel, hit `F9`. You can also use an external class, linked to your .fla, as shown in [this article](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/636/2/Getting-Started-With-AS3-and-Flash-CS3/Page2.html). It's written for CS3, but i think it'll work on CS5.

Comment: I don't always see "Document Class" when viewing the .fla document.  But I found a way: when viewing the .fla document, use File -> ActionScript Settings and you will see it and be able to change it.

Comment: The linked article is no longer available.